# GPU-friendly 2D line segment intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cuda, opencl, computational-geometry, gpgpu

I'm looking for an algorithm that tests whether 2 line segments are intersecting in a GPU-friendly way.  The line segments are in 2D.  While there are many algorithms discussed on the web for doing this, all the ones I have seen use a lot of branching instructions.  On a CPU, this is not such a problem.  However, on a GPU, a lot of branching instructions will kill performance.

Does anyone know of a good algorithm for this environment?  Any sample pseudo-code, CUDA code, OpenCL code, or DirectCompute compute would be appreciated.

---

***FOLLOW UP***

In case anyone is interested, this is (basically) what I ended up with.  I trimmed it down, so it's more like pseudo-code than OpenCL C, but hopefully it gets the gist across.

```
__kernel void findCrossingLines(__global float2 p1, __global float2 p2, 
                                __global float2 p3, __global float2 p4, 
                                __global bool* output)
{
    int result = 0;
    float2 A = p2;
    float2 a = p2 - p1;
    float2 B = p4;
    float2 b = p4 - p3;
    float2 c = B - A;
    float2 b_perp = (float2)(-b.y, b.x);

    float numerator = dot(b_perp, c);
    float denominator = dot(b_perp, a);
    bool isParallel = (denominator == 0.0f);

    float quotient = numerator / denominator;
    float2 intersectionPoint = (float2)(quotient * a.x + A.x, quotient * a.y + A.y);

    *output = (!isParallel && 
                  intersectionPoint.x >= min(p1.x, p2.x) && 
                  intersectionPoint.x >= min(p3.x, p4.x) &&
                  intersectionPoint.x <= max(p1.x, p2.x) && 
                  intersectionPoint.x <= max(p3.x, p4.x) &&
                  intersectionPoint.y >= min(p1.y, p2.y) && 
                  intersectionPoint.y >= min(p3.y, p4.y) &&
                  intersectionPoint.y <= max(p1.y, p2.y) && 
                  intersectionPoint.y <= max(p3.y, p4.y));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is outside my area of expertise, but the following thread on the NVIDIA CUDA forums discussed this topic and contains some code that may provide a useful starting point:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/intersecting-line-segments-on-gpu/18832

Note that code does not have to be completely branchless to be efficient on NVIDIA GPUs. The architecture supports predication as well as "select"-type instructions (akin to the ternary operator in C/C++), and the compiler is pretty good at mapping local branching to those branch-less constructs. I would recommend using cuobjdump to check the generated machine code, that way you'll know precisely how many branches are actually being used.

Comment: That is very helpful.  Thank you.  I am going to leave this question open just a bit longer to see if anyone else chimes up with a better answer.  Otherwise, I will award the answer to you.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess I have fixed the link. This was one of my earliest answers here. Since it is about something outside my area of expertise, I did not know how to summarize the contents of the thread on the NVIDIA forums, and (with 11 years hindsight) it would have been better to have posted this as a comment, because link rot makes the answer useless.